# OkHttp3 MockWebServer with IdlingResource

Tags: unit-testing, android-espresso, okhttp, mockwebserver

Is there a standard way to combine a `MockWebServer` with an `IdlingResource`? I guess one has to implement a custom `MockDispatcher` but the way to go is not so evident. Has anybody tried that already?